# Operation fails, but why? - On integration by substitution.

Tags: integration, logarithms

I have the following indefinite integral (picture below).

[image: My integral.]

I try integration by substitution. If I let $u = x^2 - 1$, I get a correct answer. If, however, I let $u = ln(x^2 - 1)$, then $e^u$ should equal $x^2 - 1$. Correct? ($e^ln(x^2-1) = x^2 - 1 = e^u$.)

Then why isn't it possible to subtitute $e^u$ for the quadratic term $(x^2 - 1)^2$ so that I get $(e^u)^2$?

Differentiating $\frac{du}{dx}$ and substituting terms, my integral becomes:

$$3u(e^u)^3 du$$

But this doesnt work. I dont get why the operation is not possible?

Many thanks!

Best regards,
Johanna

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your work. How did you get $3u\left(e^u\right)^3$? You said you differentiated $\frac{du}{dx}$, but what did you let $u$ equal to if you're confused about what "correct" substitution to choose? Also, I say "correct" in quotes because technically you can choose some function of $u$ to be any part of the integrand (for indefinite integrals at least); it's just a matter of trying to find the one that could help you the most.

Comment: u = ln(x^2 -1) --> du/dx = 2x/(x^2 + 1) --> 2xdx = du(x^2 + 1) --> integral becomes 3u(x^2+1)(x^2+1)^2 du = 3u(e^u)^3 = 3ue^3u du

Comment: Then integration by parts --> 3 integral ue^3u du --> let u = g(x) and e^3u = f'(x) --> 3 integral ue^3u = ue^3u/3 - integral 1*e^3u/3 = 3(ue^3u/3 - e^3u/9) = ue^3u - e^3u/3 = e^3u(u-1/3) --> substitute back --> e^3ln(x^2-1)(ln(x^2-1)-1/3) = (x^2-1)^3(ln(x^2-1)-1/3). And it should of course not have been x^2+1 in my previous comment.

Comment: It does actually work. I must have made some mistake repeatedly before. Thx for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3u(e^{u})^{3} = 3u e^{3u}$ can be easily integrated using integration by parts. The solution you should arrive at is the following: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+3ue%5E%283u%29.

Then you have to *substitute back* $u = \ln(x^2-1)$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F3+e%5E%283+u%29+%28-1+%2B+3+u%29+where+u+%3D+ln%28x%5E2-1%29

The result you get does differentiate to the integrand: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx+1%2F3+%28-1+%2B+x%5E2%29%5E3+%28-1+%2B+3+log%28-1+%2B+x%5E2%29%29

Comment: Thanks, and I did use integration by parts after my substitution. But when I differentiate back I dont get the original integrand. So somehow my substitution fails?

Comment: Edited with the following steps, it works for me !

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me too now manually. I made a mistake before. Thx for your input!

Comment: You're welcome, please accept my answer if it helped you! good luck!